# Remove ::before CSS from background image with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I want to remove in :before background image.

Php file,

```
    <li class="vi">
    <a href="javascript:;">
<span class="play-btn"></span><img src="/v1.jpg" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Nxj8BWiyypQ?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1" class="videoGPoster"> 
    </a>
    <h5>Videos 2</h5>
    </li>
```

CSS,

```
    .home_gallery .gallery_wheel .recent_photpvideo ul li.vi:before {
        position: absolute;
        top: 30%;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        content: "";
        background: url(images/play.png);
        background-size: cover;
        left: 30%;
        transform: translate(0%,0%);

.play-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    content: "";
    background: url(images/play.png);
    background-size: cover;
    left: 30%;
    transform: translate(0%,0%);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

JS File,

```
jQuery('img.videoGPoster').click(function () {
    video = '<iframe width="400" height="300" src="' + jQuery(this).attr('data-video') + '" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    jQuery(this).replaceWith(video);
});
```

I have use this code after but its not working,

```
jQuery('.play-btn').click(function () {
    alert();

    video = '<iframe width="400" height="300" src="' + jQuery(this).attr('data-video') + '" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

    jQuery(this).replaceWith(video);
});
```

Image is => https://prnt.sc/idkci7

I want to click on image button then play a video then play button not display but now play button is displayed. Please anyone help how to remove play button on :before with jquery. => https://prnt.sc/idkeop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't select pseudo selectors with jQuery so you can't directly modify its behavior. But with jQuery you can add a class or remove a class to the DOM element say `li` in this case. And then you can use CSS properties to it.

```js
jQuery('img.videoGPoster').click(function () {
    video = '<iframe width="400" height="300" src="' + jQuery(this).attr('data-video') + '" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    
    jQuery(this).parents("li.vi").addClass("playing");
    jQuery(this).replaceWith(video);
});
```

```css
li.vi {
 position: relative;
}

li.vi:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    content: "";
    background: url(http://img.jetbitts.com/android/thumbs/ico/0/google-play-android.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    left: 30%;
    transform: translate(0%,0%);
}

li.vi.playing:before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="vi">
   <a href="javascript:;"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/10/13/04/13/scenery-2846777_960_720.jpg" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Nxj8BWiyypQ?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1" class="videoGPoster"> 
   </a>
   <h5>Videos 2</h5>
</li>

<li class="vi">
   <a href="javascript:;"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/10/13/04/13/scenery-2846777_960_720.jpg" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Nxj8BWiyypQ?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1" class="videoGPoster"> 
   </a>
   <h5>Videos 2</h5>
</li>
```

Comment: but  one more issue I have 2 images in 1 loop and I have click on 1 image then both play button is display none.

Comment: Then you can use some parent child or sibling relations in jQuery to detect the exact image to hide. Check the updated answer where I have used .parents() to solve the issue

Comment: one more thing my designer add to play button on the image then my video is not working. check my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove `Pseudo-elements` directly with `jQuery` but you can set `:before` on a certain `class` then remove this class with `jQuery`

```js
jQuery('img.videoGPoster').click(function() {
  video = '<iframe width="400" height="300" src="' + jQuery(this).attr('data-video') + '" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
  jQuery(this).replaceWith(video);
  jQuery('.vi').removeClass('bg');
});
```

```css
li.bg:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  content: "";
  background: url(images/play.png);
  background-size: cover;
  left: 30%;
  transform: translate(0%, 0%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="vi bg">
  <a href="javascript:;"><img src="/v1.jpg" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Nxj8BWiyypQ?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1" class="videoGPoster">
  </a>
  <h5>Videos 2</h5>
</li>
```